# separate a string from records with changing patterns

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring

I have data in an excel file like this. As a sample, I am posting only 2 records here as a sample and there are 10000 total records like these.

```
1) 8984 Beachwood Rd Wasaga Beach ON L9Z 2X8 Phone: (705) 422-1000 Fax: (705) 422-1006
2)Bronte Health Centre 78 Jones Street Oakville ON L6L 6C5 Phone: (905) 827-9865
Fax: (905) 827-3583
```

These strings are in a single cell under a column `PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC`. Now I want to extract the fax numbers out of these records only. Manually doing is not an option because there are many. I understand the basics of SQL so if anyone can help me suggest a query which can extract only fax number out of these records and put it in a new column would be helpful for me to proceed further with my project as I am stuck here. I searched online and found substring and splitstring functions of SQL but have no idea on how I can use them here. Any guidance on how to approach this issue would be great.

Comment: Why not extract that information in excel itself and then import to DB?

Comment: I suppose [Excel has regular expression capabilities](https://www.experts-exchange.com/articles/1336/Using-Regular-Expressions-in-Visual-Basic-for-Applications-and-Visual-Basic-6.html). I would just export to CSV and then use `grep`. MS SQL does not have these, though: only pattern matching, not extraction.

Comment: You can use a function like thiss in excel `=RIGHT(A1, LEN(A1) - 4 -SEARCH("Fax:", A1))`
Where A1 is the cell wth data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanation:**
I used [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to find the position of word Fax in the line,and then used [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function to take out everything from the line(first argument to substring) from the value returned by charindex function(second argument) till end, using the length of string as last argument

<kbd>**[See live demo](https://rextester.com/DJCI40648)**</kbd>

```
create table yourtable ([PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC] nvarchar(max));
insert into yourtable values
('8984 Beachwood Rd Wasaga Beach ON L9Z 2X8 Phone: (705) 422-1000 Fax: (705) 422-1006'),
('Bronte Health Centre 78 Jones Street Oakville ON L6L 6C5 Phone: (905) 827-9865 Fax: (905) 827-3583');

select 
 Fax=
     CASE 
       WHEN CHARINDEX('Fax',[PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC])=0 THEN NULL -- case added when no Fax word in string
       ELSE SUBSTRING([PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC],CHARINDEX('Fax',[PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC]),LEN([PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC]))
     END
from yourtable
```

Comment: thank you for the answer your solution meets my requirement...if you can explain to me the select query part that would be very nice of you.

Comment: @zainulabidin updated answer for no fax word in the sentence case as well added explanation and links

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use a simple programming language like python for a task like this, if you want to format that table python will do the job

1. Wrap the hole string
2. Detect key words like Phone and Fax , in this phase you should have and array with 3 elements like `[8984 Beachwood Rd Wasaga Beach ON L9Z 2X8, Phone: (705) 422-1000,Fax: (705) 422-1006 ]`
3. Then with a python library insert in the excel with the desire format

---

Also I found the below link useful:

> https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3639-excel-extract-part-of-string.html

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this with right function assuming fax is always the last value in the column,

```
declare @table table(
[PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC] varchar(max))

insert into @table
values('8984 Beachwood Rd Wasaga Beach ON L9Z 2X8 Phone: (705) 422-1000 Fax: (705) 422-1006'),('Bronte Health Centre 78 Jones Street Oakville ON L6L 6C5 Phone: (905) 827-9865
Fax: (905) 827-3583')

SELECT
RIGHT([PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC],len([PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC])-CHARINDEX('Fax',[PRIMARY PRACTICE LOC])-3) as Fax
from  @table
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [SUBSTRING](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [PATINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/patindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [CHARINDEX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/charindex-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) functions to find where the fax number starts (i.e. to search for `Fax:` pattern), find the space after the fax number and copy the sub-string between them.

```
select *, SUBSTRING(data.row, fax.idx + 5, IIF(SpaceAfter.idx < 1, 20, SpaceAfter.idx - 1))
from (values
('8984 Beachwood Rd Wasaga Beach ON L9Z 2X8 Phone: (705) 422-1000 Fax: (705) 422-1006 '),
('Bronte Health Centre 78 Jones Street Oakville ON L6L 6C5 Phone: (905) 827-9865 Fax: (905) 827-3583')) data(row)
cross apply (select PATINDEX('%Fax: %', data.row) as idx) fax
cross apply (select CHARINDEX(' ', data.row, fax.idx + 15) as idx) SpaceAfter
```

The first cross apply finds where `Fax:` text its. We will start copying 5 chars after this index. The second cross apply finds the space after the fax number. If there is no space, the IIF function will copy tell SUBSTRING to copy next 20 symbols.

Of course, you may add additional validations, for example is there `Fax:` text at all:

```
IIF(fax.idx = 0, null, SUBSTRING(data.row, fax.idx + 5, IIF(SpaceAfter.idx < 1, 20, SpaceAfter.idx - 1)))
```

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you to do it on excel and then import to DB (if you need)

just go to Data => Text To Columns
Then separate by colon and play a bit with the columns.

It will be much more quicker.

[image]

Comment: Can be problematic as number of spaces in each record may vary thus resulting in   different number of columns for each record.

Comment: Correct, so by colon